# passing cookie info with curl in php

Tags: php, cookies, curl

Hello and thank you for helping me with my project. So I have successfully created a script to log into my my chat, but when I try to execute the second part of the curl it says I need to log in to post a message. The first curl works by it self and logs in. So how can I stay logged in with the first curl and then move to the second part to post a message?

```
/* =================================================================== 
login set cookie
====================================================================== */
$clogin = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($clogin, CURLOPT_URL, $Login_URL);
curl_setopt ($clogin, CURLOPT_REFERER, $Referer);
curl_setopt ($clogin, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $Agent);
curl_setopt ($clogin, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $Cookie_Location);
curl_setopt ($clogin, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $Cookie_File); 
curl_setopt ($clogin, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($clogin, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Login_Data);
curl_setopt ($clogin, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec   ($clogin);

/* =================================================================== 
post message
====================================================================== */

$cpost = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($cpost, CURLOPT_URL, $Posting_URL);
curl_setopt ($cpost, CURLOPT_REFERER, $Login_URL);
curl_setopt ($cpost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $Agent);
curl_setopt ($cpost, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $Cookie_Location);
curl_setopt ($cpost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $Cookie_File); 
curl_setopt ($cpost, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($cpost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Posting_Data);
curl_setopt ($cpost, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec   ($cpost);
curl_close($cpost);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear you're setting CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR (write) in your first request, but not reading from the same file in your second request CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE (read)

Comment: Don't forget to create a random filename in the temp folder instead of using a commonly named filename under your current path, better yet shy away from cookiejar/cookiefile and instead read the raw headers that return from the curl process. You can then pass the cookie information back to your second request with CURLOPT_COOKIE, even to the point of using data data of a returned sessionid.

Comment: whoa! haha this sounds complicated i have only been using curl since today. any way you could show me what you are talking about or maybe a guide or tutorial online?

Comment: @FAFAFOHI we know you are using CURL. His (@Scuzzy) suggestion is correct. It's not a correct way to use both functions (CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE) in same (first) request. - continue...

Comment: You just set the $Cookie_Location like this, before the first section
$Cookie_Location = tempnam ("/tmp", "COOKIEFILENAME");
"tempnam" - this function create a unique file name (for more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)
#1 first section:
curl_setopt ($clogin, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $Cookie_Location);
#2 Second section: 
curl_setopt ($cpost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $Cookie_Location);

So, you can access any pages with using COOKIE file, after login.

Answer (score 0):

If its your own chat app couldn't you create a token of some sort and pass that in as a get parameter each time and authenticate yourself, rather than doing it through a cookie?